# Открываются не все view элементы в LinearLayout

Tags: android, view, android-linearlayout, cardview, viewgroup

Есть cardView в ней есть linearLayout с шестью элементами

```
<LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/CardDetail"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:background="#e1e1e1"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:id="@+id/edit">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Редактировать список"
                        android:id="@+id/textView"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                    <ImageView
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_edit"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:id="@+id/remove">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Удалить список"
                        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                    <ImageView
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_remove"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:id="@+id/upload">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Загрузить в центр загрузок"
                        android:id="@+id/textView3"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                    <ImageView
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_upload"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:background="#e1e1e1"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
```

Изначально его видимость стоит на gone, но при нажатии на кнопку я делаю LinearLayout Видимым (View.Visible) и делаю к нему анимацию раскрывания cardView, но вместо того чтоб стали видимы все элементы, становиться видим только один второй элемент.

Вот код анимации и нахождения высоты

```
package ru.landmarkstd.educt.FunctionalClass;

import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.Transformation;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class ExpandAndCollapce
{
    public static void expand(CardView cardView,final ViewGroup v, int duration)
    {
        slide(cardView,v, duration, true);
    }

    public static void collapse(CardView cardView,final ViewGroup v, int duration)
    {
        slide(cardView,v, duration, false);
    }

    private static void slide(final CardView cardView, final ViewGroup v, int duration, final boolean expand)
    {
        try
        {
            Method m = v.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("onMeasure", int.class, int.class);
            m.setAccessible(true);
            m.invoke(
                    v,
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(((View) v.getParent()).getMeasuredWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST),
                    View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
            );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("slideAnimation", e.getMessage(), e);
        }

        final int initialHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();

        if (expand)
        {
            v.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            v.getLayoutParams().height = initialHeight;
        }
        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        Animation a = new Animation()
        {
            @Override
            protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t)
            {
                int newHeight = 0;
                if (expand)
                {
                    newHeight = (int) (initialHeight * interpolatedTime);
                }
                else
                {
                    newHeight = (int) (initialHeight * (1 - interpolatedTime));
                }
                v.getLayoutParams().height = newHeight;
                v.requestLayout();

                if (interpolatedTime == 1 && !expand)
                {
                    v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean willChangeBounds()
            {
                return true;
            }
        };

        a.setDuration(duration);
        v.startAnimation(a);
    }
}
```

Это полный макет cardView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp">

                    <CheckBox
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="Название списка"
                        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:theme="@style/MyCheckBox"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:minLines="1" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/textView4"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:text="Арифметика" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/open"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_open_card"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/CardDetail"
                android:visibility="gone">

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:background="#e1e1e1"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:id="@+id/edit">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Редактировать список"
                        android:id="@+id/textView"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                    <ImageView
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_edit"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:id="@+id/remove">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Удалить список"
                        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                    <ImageView
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_remove"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:id="@+id/upload">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Загрузить в центр загрузок"
                        android:id="@+id/textView3"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                    <ImageView
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_upload"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:background="#e1e1e1"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

А это код вызова анимации из основного активити

```
open = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.open);
cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
linearLayoutDetails = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.CardDetail);

holder.open.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if (holder.linearLayoutDetails.getVisibility() == View.GONE)
                {
                    ExpandAndCollapce.expand(holder.cv,holder.linearLayoutDetails, 500);

                    ObjectAnimator rotation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "rotation", 180);
                    rotation.setDuration(500);
                    rotation.start();
                }
                else
                {
                    ExpandAndCollapce.collapse(holder.cv,holder.linearLayoutDetails, 500);

                    ObjectAnimator rotation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(v, "rotation", 0);
                    rotation.setDuration(500);
                    rotation.start();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: а в Preview у вас все вьюхи отображаються?

Comment: Если ставлю visible то да

Comment: а попробуйте заминить GONE на INVISIBLE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все решилось очень просто, у всех элементов в linear layout стоял match_parent, с установкой wrap_content все изменилось